# Sample or population beta weights in R's lm() and lme()?

Tags: r, linear-regression, nlme, multilevel-analysis

A journal is asking whether I report sample or population beta weights for my regressions. I am using the lm() function in base R and the lme() function from the nlme-package. Which kind of beta weight do they give? I was not able to find any information on this in the package documentations.

Comment: If we perform an `lm()` with a sample data, we would report the beta estimate, i.e. an estimate of population beta which we got through sample. Moreover, we report the S.E. and confidence interval also. It suggests that the population's beta may fall within the confidence interval. You may check some reference documents as well, before replying to the journal.

Comment: I assume that there are different ways to calculate beta weights, similar to R² and adjusted R², depending on whether they are sample or population estimates.